# Need to convert epoch time to EST using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I do have a dataframe like this  -> df

```
     timestamp      values

0    1574288141       34  
1    1574288241       23
2    1574288341       22
3    1574288441       10
```

Here timestamp has the epoch time. I want to convert this into a **datetime** in the format `2019-11-20 04:03:01`. I would like to convert this into a **EST date**.
When I do

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')
```

I get the conversion and the required format but the time doesn't seem to be in **EST**. It is 4 hours ahead of **EST**. 
I have tried to convert utc to Eastern using the code

`pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s').tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')`

But I am getting an error

```
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should adding `dt` , since your input is `series` not `index`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp,unit='s').dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
Out[8]: 
0   2019-11-20 17:15:41-05:00
1   2019-11-20 17:17:21-05:00
2   2019-11-20 17:19:01-05:00
3   2019-11-20 17:20:41-05:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```